# Bootstrap doesn't work with apache

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded a bootstrap template and put it in /www/html/ and on opening the index.html file the page opens just fine , but when i start the apache and open the site with the browser by going to localhost the font disappear and the pictures leaving a static web page

Comment: Check your browser console to see potential errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly look at is whether or not it's a path issue with your styleheets. If path is correct then You can use Developer tools in google chrome or other browser and in the sources tab look for errors. Two common errors are your css files not being found maybe your file permissions don't allow the Apache server to access the CSS files.